# My Own Controller Method in Auth Facade in Laravel 5.1

Tags: laravel, facade

I want to add my own controller method to Auth Facade in Laravel

```
auth()->user()->ownControllerMethod()
```

How can we do that ?

Comment: You want to add this particular method? I mean chaining it through `user()` method?

Answer (score 1):

In your example, you'd actually be adding a method to the User model. (User.php)

```
public function my_method() {

    // code here 
}
```

EDIT:

Per your comment, lets say your route is mapped to the `index()` method in your `UsersController`, you could do this:

```
public function index() 
{
    // some code

    $this->doSomething();

}

protected function doSomething()
{
    // some code

    // return data
}
```

But it really depends what this method is meant to do. There's lots of different ways to break up your code. And depending on the size of your project, your `User` model maybe a fine place.

Comment: i know i can do it like that. But i think i misunderstood Model Concept. I know that Model is for dealing DB. I wan to use Controller Method (like UserController)

Comment: Well what will this method be doing? Controllers are meant to handle requests. So, for example, if a user goes to a certain URL, you'd have a controller method that handles this request (and routes.php takes care of that mapping). You can also add public/private method within your UserController. I'll add an example in my answer